# angularjs: can't get the isolated scope property via this keyword in controller with v1.6.2

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

In my angularjs project, I came into a strange issue. I don't have live demo, but try to describe my issue and debugging as detail as possible below:

I have a custom directive as following:

```
<div app-position-class  company-info="company.company" position-class="company.positionclass"></div>
```

from the parent controller I passed into the directive two parameters:`company.company` and `company.positionclass`.

and the directive is defined as following:

```
function appPositionClassCtrl(){
    console.log(this)
    console.log(this.companyInfo);  
}

function appPositionClassDirective(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl : 'view/template/positionClass.html',
        scope: {
             positionClass: "=",
             companyInfo : "="
        },
        bindToController: true,
        controller: 'appPositionClassCtrl',
        controllerAs:"posiClass"
    };  
 }
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('appPositionClass',appPositionClassDirective)
    .controller('appPositionClassCtrl',appPositionClassCtrl);
```

so I get the two passed in properties within the `scope` object. And in my controller function `appPositionClassCtrl`, I want to do something with that data.

```
function appPositionClassCtrl(){
    console.log(this)
    console.log(this.companyInfo);  
}
```

But I found the `this.companyInfo` is `Undefined`. The confusing point is `console.this` has correct output as following:

```
appPositionClassCtrl
companyInfo:Object
positionClass:Array[2]
__proto__:Object
```

I can't reproduce this issue with simple live demo, but I can't fix it neither after many debugging.
So any help?

Edited: 
I reproduce the issue with this live demo. 
https://jsfiddle.net/baoqger/rbp1wyfa/4/

And I found the that the behaviors are different between different version. In my application, I use angular 1.6.2, and then I came across this issue. In the current demo, if If change the version to 1.4.8, then the issue is fixed.

But I want to know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The scope hasn't had a chance to bind to the controller yet.

in your appPositionClassCtrl() replace everything with this:

```
this.$onInit = function() {
    console.log(this.companyInfo);
}
```

you can be 100% sure the scope will be bound to the controller after $onInit is called.

More information about this can be found here: [AngularJS API: $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile). In particular this part:

> After the controller is instantiated, the initial values of the isolate scope bindings will be bound to the controller properties. You can access these bindings once they have been initialized by providing a controller method called $onInit, which is called after all the controllers on an element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized.